# How to declare a class with a constructior outside of a function C++

Tags: c++, class

I have a simple question that I haven't been able to find an answer to.

If I have a class with a constructor, for example,

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int var);
    ~Test();
};
```

and I want to declare it outside of main, as a static global

For example.

```
static Test test1;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I will get an error:
`no matching function for call to 'Test::Test()'`

If I try to use 
`static Test test1(50);`
I will get errors: Undefined reference

What is the right way to do this? Do I need to have 2 constructors, one empty and 1 with variable?

Thanks,

Comment: It is trying to call the default constructor, which does not exist.  You defined a constructor that accepts an integer, so you either need to pass an integer to the constructor or define a constructor without parameters.

Comment: Would a constructor that takes no arguments ever be *useful* in your program?

Comment: Better for you not knowing: `static Test test(1);` (Please avoid it)

Comment: Linux and windows tags has nothing to do with this question!

Comment: You most probably missed to provide a definition for your constructor function, or to link the file that contains it.

Comment: Provide defination for the member functions  
`class Test
{
public:
    Test(){}
  Test(int var){}
  ~Test(){}
};

static Test test1(5);
int main()
{
   return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to provide an implementation for your class constructors and destructor (even an empty implementation), e.g.:

> ```
> class Test
> {
> public:
>   Test()  // constructor with no parameters, i.e. default ctor
>   {
>       // Do something
>   }
>
>   Test(int var)
>   // or maybe better:
>   //
>   //   explicit Test(int var)
>   {
>       // Do something for initialization ...
>   }
>
>   // BTW: You may want to make the constructor with one int parameter
>   // explicit, to avoid automatic implicit conversions from ints.
>
>   ~Test()
>   {
>       // Do something for cleanup ...
>   }
> };
> ```